# OCR using pi and pi cam

Tags: camera, raspbian-jessie, raspicam, noobs

I am working on an OCR project. I use raspberry pi 3(model b) for OCR. 
Can pi cam be used to detect texts?... Does pi cam provide sufficient clarity to detect texts clearly in an image? If so how could clarity be increased to detect texts precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually you can do that. The Raspberry Pi Cams (especially the new ones) offer good enough quality in my opinion. However, the performance will depend on the whole product: So you should have a fixed position from the cam to the object you want to scan, good lighting, both cam and object should not move too much for best results - and in the end you'll have to translate the images to text via ocr applications. A good starting point is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553156/5730361
However, I would recommend using a normal flat-bed scanner, as the performance and price of the final product as well as the usablity will be much higher. But for the sake of learning something new and not building a product - go for it :)!